# Add '#' beside each wordpress tag

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, hashtag

I'm trying to add hashtags beside my post tags in Wordpress.

With this code, it looks like : tag1, tag2, tag3

```
<?php the_tags( '<span class="meta-sep"> | </span><span class="tag-links">' . __( '', 'portfoliopress' ) . '</span>', ', ', '' ); ?>
```

But I'd like to change it to : #tag1, #tag2, #tag3

I tried to add # into this part

> ', ', ', '' ); ?>

but it gave me a fatal error. I don't know PHP, but it seems like a simple task.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Not sure where you added it, but perhaps this: <?php the_tags( '<span class="meta-sep"> | </span><span class="tag-links">#' . __( '', 'portfoliopress' ) . '</span>', ', ', '' ); ?>

Comment: Yes, I got confused by all the ', ' I placed the hashtag in the wrong one. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php the_tags( '#', ', #', '' ); ?>
```

**EDIT**: to add the # to the link text:

```
if( $tags = get_the_tags() ) {
    echo '<span class="meta-sep"> | </span>';
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        $sep = ( $tag === end( $tags ) ) ? '' : ', ';
        echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $tag, $tag->taxonomy ) . '">#' . $tag->name . '</a>' . $sep;
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you'd like to keep the separator: `the_tags( '<span class="meta-sep"> | </span>#', ', #', '' );`

Comment: Thanks, got confused by all the ', '. I read the codex, doesn't seem to be way to include the links onto the hashtags. Oh well

Comment: You didn't have to do that! It worked perfectly, thanks! So nice of you