# How to insert # inside this code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I found tutorial on how to add **#** in every tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705398/add-beside-each-wordpress-tag?newreg=1ef7a067142248efb2358a257f14b5f1), but I don't know how to apply it into this code.

How to put **#** in this code?

```
<?php 
if ( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, APP_TAX_TAG ) ) 
     echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, APP_TAX_TAG, '', '', '' ); 
else 
     _e( 'No Tags', APP_TD ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might use `get_the_terms`

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, APP_TAX_TAG);
$prefix = "#";

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error($terms) ) {
    $tag_links = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $href = get_term_link($term, APP_TAX_TAG);
        $tag_links[] = '<a href="' . $href . '">' . $prefix . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
    echo join(", ", $tag_links);
} else {
    _e( 'No Tags', APP_TD ); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks you @avsej,this code working! [link](http://rebung.my/ads/marine-essence-bodywash) .Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

to add the # to the link text:

```
<?php
if ( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, APP_TAX_TAG ) ) 
     $tagsString = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, APP_TAX_TAG, '', '', '' ); 
     $tagsString = preg_replace("#href=\"([^\"])\"#","#href=\"$1\#\"#",$tagsString);
     echo $tagsString;
else 
     _e( 'No Tags', APP_TD ); 
?>
```

Should work properly ;)

Comment: I have try,give error,but thank you @David ,appreaciate your interest to help.I used avsej code,and it's work